# How to toggle on / off microphone using Python and also get its current state?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, microphone

I found the following code that toggles off / on the microphone using Python and it works well (only on windows).

```
import win32api
import win32gui

WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319
APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x180000

hwnd_active = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32api.SendMessage(hwnd_active, WM_APPCOMMAND, None, APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE)
```

However, I could not find in any place how to get the state of the microphone (if it's muted or not). How can I do that?

And is there a way to achieve toggle on / off microphone + getting its state functionallity in non-windows computers?

Thanks